# ROS Answers SE migration: manipulator

Tags: ros, manipulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there. i want to make a manipulator either 6 DOF or 3 DOF. is there any packages/tutorial available for ROS indigo version ????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249496/manipulator/) by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You can create manipulator of any DOF and configure it using Moveit:Motion planning framework.
For installation and tutorials ,click this
[MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/)

---

Originally posted by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) with karma: 243 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arpitsoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/27421/arpitsoni/) on 2016-12-09**:
hi gokul... i saw ur profile. r u also working on manipulator???? plz mail me at soniarpit30@gmail.com... i need some guidance... did u build manipulator by ur own or bought ready-made as if u r in college/industry ???

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
Ya . I am working on a custom made manipulator from the company. But I can help you out in building a manipulator too, if you need. Ping me at astrogok@gmail.com

**Comment by [Gokul](https://answers.ros.org/users/25955/gokul/) on 2016-12-12**:
If you are convinced with the answer, just upvote it and mark it as complete. So ,that it will be helpful for others.